# G2 Gensym post from C#

Tags: gensym

I am trying to past a message to system G2, but I get error, No overload for method 'PostMessage' takes 2 arguments. Can you please help, thks

```
  private void PostMsgBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object[] C1_ob = new object[1];
        C1_ob[0] = 1;

        axG2Gateway1.PostMessage(MsgToPost.Text , ref (C1_ob));
        
    }
```

Comment: As the name implies, the `PostMessage()` method do not accept 2 arguments. But you passed 2 arguments (1. `MsgToPost.Text`, 2. `ref(C1_ob)`)

Comment: When you look at the PostMessage, it asks for (ref object Message), so it seems that I have to send it somehow as one

Comment: Is there any documentation you can refer? I guess maybe `PostMessage(ref (MsgToPost.Text));` will do?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it now works

Comment: It will be grateful if you could vote up my comments if they helped. :)

Comment: object C1_ob = MsgToPost.Text;
            axG2Gateway1.PostMessage(ref C1_ob);